# Prevent SQL injection

Tags: 8, security

One of the security principles is sanitize string and variables passed from client to server; SQL injection is one of the way to hack a website. in plain PHP there are some functions to prevent SQL injection:

- [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

What is Drupal 8 strategy to prevent SQL injection? How can I clean up client data post in my Controller to protect my site from SQL injection?

Comment: This'll wind up being closed as too broad in its current state, best practice around sanitising input is a larger topic then Q+A would deal with in one go. It'd be better to concentrate on a single area at a time and ask separate questions about each. For example, handling SQL injection and XSS prevention are completely different things, and wouldn't usually be talked about in the same breath

Comment: @Clive you right, some  I divide it in two question, SQL Injection and XSS, ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Drupal 8 (like Drupal 7) uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to communicate with databases.

With PDO, the DB API makes use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), specifically to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Practically, this means that you should use the database API methods. If you use the `select`, `update`, `delete` methods directly, you have a better chance of avoiding SQL injection as everything will be parameterised.

If you use `query`, you need to be more careful, as the API can only protect you so much. For example, if you do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE name = '$_GET[name]'";
\Drupal::database->query($sql);
```

Then you deserve what you get :) You should always use this instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE name = :name";
\Drupal::database->query($sql, [':name' => $_GET['name']]);
```

Aside: In reality, you'll only see the 2 functions you mentioned being used in very old, practically obsolete code these days. The MySQL extension has been removed now, and `stripslashes` was traditionally used with magic quotes, which were deprecated in PHP 5.3. SQL injection is still very much a problem, but those 2 perhaps aren't the best to use for comparison in this day and age.

Comment: More good extra info here **[Drupal 8: Writing secure code](https://www.drupal.org/node/2489544)**

Comment: thanks alot, you mean if I want to use  something like `userAuth->authenticate($name,$pass);`, it is not required I sanitize user and password  for SQL injection  danger before calling authenticate method?

Comment: No, you're a few levels up when you use methods like that, no need to think about SQL injection. There's always the outside chance that Drupal itself has a nasty vulnerability (think drupalgeddon), which would invalidate that statement, but in "peace times" as it were, you don't need to think about it

Comment: @Clive as always good  and comprehensive answer. thanks a lot.I learn from your answer :)